# Autowired issue/No bean found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to implement Spring Boot and setting up my user service. I am having trouble with the error about not being able to find the UserService bean. Any suggestions or direction would be appreciated.

UserController

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final IUserService userService;

    @Inject
    public UserController(final IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public FBUser createUser(@RequestBody @Valid final FBUser fBUser) {
        return userService.save(fBUser);
    }
}
```

IUserService

```
public interface IUserService {

    FBUser save(FBUser fBUser);
}
```

UserService

```
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    private final IUserRepository repository;

    @Inject
    public UserService(final IUserRepository repository) {
         this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public FBUser save(final FBUser fBUser) {
        return repository.save(fBUser);
    }

}
```

IUserRepository

```
public interface IUserRepository extends JpaRepository<FBUser, Long> {
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [/Users/christopher/workspace/FeedAndBedding/target/classes/com/creativefuhsion/controllers/UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.creativefuhsion.services.impls.UserService]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.creativefuhsion.services.impls.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.creativefuhsion.services.impls.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
    at com.creativefuhsion.FeedAndBeddingApplication.main(FeedAndBeddingApplication.java:16)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.creativefuhsion.services.impls.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 18 more
```

Comment: You're very likely using JDK proxies. Set `proxy-class` to true in your `@Transactional` configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotate your user service with `@Service`:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {
```

Otherwise Spring won't find it when it scans for things to inject.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. It's always those small mistakes. Just needed a second set of eyes.

Comment: @clenard oh yeah. Be there myself quite a few times ;)